# Cannot assign requested address (os error 99) in WSL2

Tags: proxy, localhost, vpn, wsl-2

I use wsl2 in windows11: ubuntu 20.04. And I set the proxy in the `~/.bashrc`:

```
export https_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:7890"
export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:7890"
```

I entered the following command to start an app, but it showed that I couldn't connect：

```
levi@LEVI-104-PC:/opt/solana/solana-local-validator$ solana-test-validator
--faucet-sol argument ignored, ledger already exists
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
⠓ Initializing...
Waiting for fees to stabilize 1...
Identity: 8tyfD7vG2shknYLoXWo9SQA3eNf8v8NMH5WvZnQTugnL
Genesis Hash: BaLEwHBR8Qhz7MW6xZnEffW5MT4XyrPDN2NVezyBC1nj
Version: 1.16.28
Shred Version: 52617
Gossip Address: 127.0.0.1:1024
TPU Address: 127.0.0.1:1027
JSON RPC URL: http://127.0.0.1:8899
WebSocket PubSub URL: ws://127.0.0.1:8900
  RPC connection failure: error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1:8899/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Canno
Failed to get validator identity over RPC: error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1:8899/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Cannot assign requested address (os error 99)
.......
```

My nameserver in wsl2 is: 127.0.0.42

But when I delete the proxy configuration in `~/.bashrc` and don't use the VPN in windows, it can work. What should I do to work with the proxy configuration?(I have tried different VPN proxy modes, and I want to start this app using VPN).